# What's the difference between STDIN and arguments passed to command?

Tags: io-redirection, pipe, arguments

I could use the either form to execute the `cat` method:

```
cat file_name
cat < file_name
```

The result is the same

Then I want to execute `man` in the format of `stdin`

```
man < file_name
```

While `file_name` contains:

```
# file_name
cat
```

But it pops up 
`What manual page do you want?` instead of execute `man cat`.

I want to know why `cat` could accept `stdin` as arguments but `man` cannot.  And what's the difference between command line arguments and `stdin`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your question is closely related to how the shell you are using parses user input on the command line.

If the first word on the command line is a program, located in a special folder (mostly defined by `PATH`) and no more special characters are given (depends of the shell you are using), all subsequent words separated by spaces or tabs are passed to the program in a special form i.e. an array. With each word as one element in the array.

How the program, you are going to invoke interprets the arguments (located in the array) depends on how it is programmed. There are some quasi standards of how the syntax of the arguments should look like but in general the programmer is entire free. So the first argument can be interpreted as a name of a file or whatever the programmer thoughts of at the time he wrote the program.

In the case you add the special character `<` or `>` to your command line, the shell dosn't append `<` and `>` nor subsequent words to the array that will be passed to the program. With `<` or `>` given the shell starts to make fancy things, supported by the underlying kernel (keyword [piping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)). To grasp what's going on you must understand what `STDIN` and `STDOUT` (since it's not immediately related i omit `STDERR`) are.

Everything visible you see on your terminal (in most cases a part of your display) is either written by the shell or any other program you have invoked previously to a special file (in [unix everything is a file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file)). This file has a special id and is called `STDOUT`. If a program wants to read data from the keyboard it dosn't poll the keyboard directly (at least in most cases) but reads from a special file called `STDIN`. Internally this file is connected to your standard input device, your keyboard in most cases.

If the shell reads `<` or `>` in a parsed command line it manipulates `STDIN` or `STDOUT` in a particular kind for the time the corresponding program is running. `STDIN` and `STDOUT` dosn't point to the terminal or the standard input device any longer but rather to the subsequent filename on the command line.

In the case of the two lines

```
cat file_name
cat < file_name
```

the observed behavior is identical because the corresponding developer makes `cat` to either read data from `STDIN` or read the data from the file, whose name is given as the first command line argument (which is the first element in the array the shell passes to `cat`). Subsequently `cat` writes the whole content of `file_name` or `STDIN` to the terminal since we don't instruct the shell to manipulate `STDOUT`. Remember that in the second line your shell manipulates `STDIN` in this way, that it doesn't point to your standard input device anylonger but points to a file called `file_name` in your current working directory.

In the other case of the line

```
man < file_name
```

`man` is not meant to read anything from `STDIN` if it's called with no argument i.e. an empty array. So the line

```
man < file_name
```

equals

```
man
```

For example `man` will read something from `STDIN`, too if you pass `-l -` to `man`. With this option given on the command line you can display the content of anything `man` reads from `STDIN` on your terminal. So

```
man -l - < file_name
```

would work also (but be careful `man` is not just a pager but also parses the input of the file and so the file content and the displayed content could differ).

So how `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and the command line arguments are interpreted is all up to the corresponding developer.

I hope my answer could clear things up.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. For your last few paragraphs, you mentioned use `man -l - < file_name` to make `man` interprets `STDIN` as arguments, but it fails in my system with the `STDERR`: ```man -l - < tee
man: invalid option -- l
man, version 1.6c```

Comment: You're welcome. But i didn't mention that at least my version of `man` ([man-db](http://man-db.nongnu.org/)) reads arguments from `STDIN` with the given arguments `-l` followed by `-`. It just interprets data from `STDIN` as a man page. For more detailed explanations of valid arguments and how they are interpreted you have to consult the man page of the related program. In your case consult `man  man`. Maybe there is a similar option for your `man`. If you want to read command line arguments for a specific program from `STDIN` `xargs` (like mentioned above) is the way to go.

Comment: I `man man` and find the one in my OS doesn't support it. Anyway, thanks for this declaration of these two concepts for me.

Comment: I edited your answer so it contains actually useful links instead of lmgtfy. Posting lmgtfy links is 1) rude, 2) unhelpful and 3) [really frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15650/203101) on the SE sites. Either provide a link or don't but if you choose to do so, provide a link to actual information and not to a sarcastic way of showing someone how to find it.

Comment: Little known fact : `cat <file -n` is actually equivalent to `cat -n <file` (I'm reacting to « the shell do[e]sn't append `<` and `>` nor subsequent words to the array [...] »)

Answer (score 14):

They're completely different. Command-line arguments are passed to the program in an array and it can do what it wants with them; stdin is an input stream the program has to request data from. Programs that process files often choose to support both, but they have to do so manually -- they check if a filename was passed as a command-line argument, and if not they read from stdin instead

You seem to be expecting `man` to read stdin to find the man page it should display, which would be a really strange behavior; when would you ever use that? The fact that `cat` displays its stdin is an artifact of the fact that it does nothing else; I don't think any other tool works that way. For example, `grep` can take a filename or read from `stdin`, but it processes the data on `stdin`, it doesn't read a filename from `stdin` and then open it

If you really do need this behavior, you could use `xargs`, which converts a file to command-line arguments:

```
$ xargs man < file_name
```

Or just embed a `cat` call within the `man` call:

```
$ man $(cat file_name)
```

Comment: In bash, you can use `man $(<file_name)`.

Comment: Re: "I don't think any other tool works that way" - Perl's `(<>)` in a loop will do `STDIN` or command-line arguments as filenames...

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco I meant no tool either takes an argument or reads a filename from stdin and reads the argument from that file

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Thanks for this clarification. The purpose I used `man < file_name` is to help myself understand this two concepts.  Reading you explanation, the implementation is decided by the command author. So if I under right, the `find` takes arguments rather processes STDIN?