# Is there any command that read their standard input in special cases?

Tags: command-line, input

I have been looking for lesser known commands that reads their standard input in special cases(missing arguments , for example).

I'm thinking  "cat" or  maybe other command would fit here.

Comment: I think you're going to need to define "special cases". The `cat` command will read from _stdin_ either when there are no arguments or when it encounters `-` in the list of files to process. Neither seems a particularly special case to me.

Comment: Maybe a "special case": htpasswd without option -b will prompt for the password (it is the standard way for security reasons).

Comment: Many unix/linux commands read from stdin when they aren't given filenames to process (or when the filename is `-`or, at worst, `/dev/stdin`).  It's perfectly normal and not in the least bit unusual or "special case".  There has been an unfortunate trend in recent years to write tools that are incapable of this (looking at YOU, python programmers) but they're still rare.

Comment: in short, if it seems like it would make sense or be useful for a unix tool to read from stdin, then it probably does.  if it doesn't, file a bug report :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys , the question was totally unclear to me too. I appreciate your time for answering my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few cases that come to mind:

- missing arguments,
- the special argument "-",
- the program detects that the standard input is not a terminal, and
- an option (or environment variable) overrides the behavior.

For missing arguments, `cat` is a useful example.  Likewise `grep`, `sed`.

The special argument "-" is used in several programs to tell it explicitly to read from the standard input.  You can find discussion (with examples) in these:

- [What's the difference between STDIN and arguments passed to command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46372/whats-the-difference-between-stdin-and-arguments-passed-to-command)
- [How to read stdin when no arguments are passed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619490/how-to-read-stdin-when-no-arguments-are-passed)
- [Pipe, standard input and command line arguments in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504867/pipe-standard-input-and-command-line-arguments-in-bash)

For the case where the standard input is not a terminal—offhand, the cases I'm familiar with are less known:

- [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) checks on startup if its input is a terminal, and if not, opens the terminal device.  This is part of a larger scheme where it can read data from a pipe, e.g., for the gauge widget.
- [diffstat](http://invisible-island.net/diffstat/diffstat.html) handles missing arguments by reading its input from the standard input, but in addition, its `-v` (verbose) option when *doing* this shows progress, e.g., a "." for each file
- piping to vi-like-emacs makes it read the input as a file.  vim's comparable feature (implemented [later[4](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html)), uses the explicit "-" argument.

For special arguments:

- [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html) has an option `--gauge` which reads data from the standard input. Also `--input-fd` tells it *which* file descriptor to use as its input for pipes.
- [lynx](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/Lynx_users_guide.html) has an option `-stdin` telling it to interpret the standard input as html.  Otherwise, it accepts configuration options on the standard input, e.g., using `-get_data` or `-post_data`.

Comment: No problem - there are probably similar cases for the latter part in other programs, but those come to mind first.