# Piping Output of Shuf Command

Tags: shell, scripting, pipe, shuf

Fairly new to Linux.  I have a nixie clock that runs off of a Raspberry Pi.  I would like to send a random sequence of six digits to it every so often to help prolong the life of the Nixie tubes.

There is a CLITool program I found on GitHub that lets me display any six digits using the command `CLITool xxxxxx`, where x is any digit 0-9. So I tried creating a bash file with the line  `shuf -zer -n6 {0..9}|CLITool`.

The `shuf` command produces a random six digit string of numbers, but it does not seem to get piped to the CLITool.  Like I mentioned, fairly new to Linux, so it could be something basic I am missing.

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between STDIN and arguments passed to command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46372/whats-the-difference-between-stdin-and-arguments-passed-to-command) and [Pass the output of previous command to next as an argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108782/pass-the-output-of-previous-command-to-next-as-an-argument)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use command substitution.

```
 CLITool $(expr 1+2)
```

will first run the `expr` program with an argument of `1+2`. This will output `3`. Then the shell will run `CLITool 3`.

I would use awk to get the number, e.g.

```
 CLItool $(awk 'BEGIN{srand();printf("%06d\n",rand()*1000000)}')
```

to get a 6 digit random number with leading 0s between 0 and 1,000,000-1.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your CLI tool simply doesn't read input from stdin. Only tools that can read input streams can be piped to. So just use command substitution instead:

```
CLItool $(shuf -zer -n6 {0..9})
```

Comment: This works because the command substitution effectively strips off the NUL characters that the `-z` introduces.

Comment: Thank you!  That works great.