# How to use positional parameter in docker exec command with here strings (<<<)?

Tags: bash, command-line, docker, here-string

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
    docker exec -it $1 /bin/bash <<< $CONTAINER_ID
```

But this doesn't work:

Output: "docker exec" requires at least 2 arguments.

It seems that <<< completely replaces STDIN ignoring $1. Is it possible to replace only one argument with <<<? I know about aliases, but it doesn't suit me. I need to be able to use only standard tools to pass to my colleague a command in which he will change only the last variable, which will replace one or more arguments in the center of the command.

Comment: `Here is what I am trying to do:` what is it trying to achieve? Please add examples

Comment: I want to convert this:

    `somecommand  $var arg2`

to this:

    `somecommand  $1 arg2 <<< $var`

With <<< , I'm trying to replace only the first argument, instead of completely replacing standard input (STDIN).

Comment: "Is it possible to replace only one argument with `<<<`?" – `<<<` redirects stdin and has nothing to do with arguments. Maybe you should read [*What's the difference between STDIN and arguments passed to command?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46372/108618)

Comment: that's what I thought, wasn't clear that you didn't understand the command line in the question

Comment: Considering your answer and your comment under the answer, I see an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here.

Comment: A decent solution to the actual problem revealed in your comment under your answer is `sh -c 'exec docker exec -it "$1" /bin/bash' sh "$CONTAINER_ID"`. It's not an answer to the question in its current form though.

Answer (score 0):

`<<<` is the wrong tool for this job. It replaces standard input (stdin), which has nothing to do with passing arguments. Arguments and stdin are both forms of input to a command, but they're completely separate from each other. `xargs` can convert stdin to arguments, but at that point you're really trying to work around the problem instead of using a method that doesn't have this problem in the first place.

I'm not sure I understand what the actual goal and constraints here, but I think defining a function might be the cleanest way to accomplish what you want:

```
execit() {
    docker exec -it "$1" /bin/bash
}
```

(Replacing `execit` with whatever function name you prefer.) Then just run e.g. `execit "$CONTAINER_ID"`.

If that doesn't fit what you're trying to do, the next cleanest solution is what Kamil Maciorowski suggested in a comment:

```
sh -c 'exec docker exec -it "$1" /bin/bash' sh "$CONTAINER_ID"
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to Kamil Maciorowski, I figured out which way to look and found a solution. Here is the command that does what I need:

```
xargs -o -I{} docker exec -it {} /bin/bash <<< $CONTAINER_ID
```

Comment: What is wrong with `docker exec -it "$CONTAINER_ID" /bin/bash`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski my task was to move the container name argument to the right. This makes it possible to copy a command from an internal work instruction, and then quickly replace the container name on the right with the desired one, without changing anything in the center.

Comment: @AntonKuznetsov, that's not what your question says, though.

Comment: Ditto. And frankly only after you published your answer I understood what you wanted the command to do.

Comment: A oneline function is probably still better even for this: `f() { docker exec -it "$1" /bin/bash ; }; f "$CONTAINER_ID"`